# Pass DII out-argument in Java CORBA

Tags: java, corba, idl

I have the following IDL interface:

```
  interface ItemA : Item {
     void actionA(in float a, out long b);
  };
```

In my Java implementation I'd like to invoke the operation `actionA` dynamically (using DII). The `item` object here implements `Item` interface and therefore knows nothing about the `actionA`. Here's the snippet:

```
org.omg.CORBA.Request r = item._request("actionA");
r.add_in_arg().insert_float(a);
// add the out argument
r.set_return_type(orb.get_primitive_tc(org.omg.CORBA.TCKind.tk_void));
r.invoke();
// get the out argument result
```

How can I fill in those blanks? I've tried various approaches, mainly different uses of `r.add_out_arg()` but nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
org.omg.CORBA.Request r = item._request("actionA");
r.add_in_arg().insert_float(a);
Any val = r.add_out_arg();
val.type(orb.get_primitive_tc(TCKind.tk_long));
r.set_return_type(orb.get_primitive_tc(org.omg.CORBA.TCKind.tk_void));
r.invoke();

if( r.env().exception() == null )
{
    System.out.println("returned: " + r.arguments().item(1).value().extract_long());  
}
```

It worked for me (I've already seen this idl somewhere...:P).

Comment: Strange tu stumble upon people from your own university on SO. BTW. You certainly realize, that it's a bit too late now :)